# Godot cutout animation with skeletons and ragdoll physics

Tags: 2d, physics, godot

i'm following the tutorial for [cutout animation](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/animation/cutout_animation.html), but also wanted to combine [ragdoll physics from this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uGD_8mT_vi4), my goal is to make a 2d fight game with this 2 techniques. but not sure how to combine them both at the same time,  from **what i have learned the cutout animation will do whatever animation is doing at the moment, but how to switch to ragdoll physics at the moment the dummy is hit?.**

Is this correct?

Comment: This is something that I have been unable to get working correctly. However, I'm convinced that it is going to be following the approach of the video, and then animating it. I'm afraid I can't help more than that. Godot needs a build in skeleton ragdoll solution for 2D. It has it for 3D.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have been dealing with this problem too.

Unfortunately, the Skeleton2D and Bone2D seems to be tools for animators only (it is not a physics object). There is support for 3D ragdoll with PhysicalBone but Godot is lacking in terms of 2D.

I had to switch to Unity for my 2D ragdolls. There is a built-in tool for 2D Skeletons and you can make them physical objects with ease. Also, you already have HingeJoint2D present there which is again lacking in Godot.

Or you could wait for Godot 4.0 It seems like they are improving the IK system and adding PhysicalBone2D. https://github.com/godotengine/godot/pull/47872